ShadCn Combobox on Form - onSelect (from CommandItem) does not connect the selected value from Combobox with the defined field on the form
my issue with the ShadCn Combobox on Form is that onSelect (from CommandItem) cannot connect the  value from Combobox with the form's field.

The constant for Combobox is called - serviceCategories.
The field on form (with zod validations) is called - serviceCategory.
After selecting the value from the Combobox, it is properly shown on the form, but after submitting the form, all other fields are updated in the database, except the value coming from the Combobox,  showing "null".

Is there a way to console.log values from CommandItem?
Here is the excerpt from my code:
                    <CommandList>
                      <CommandEmpty>Not found.</CommandEmpty>
                      <CommandGroup>
                        {serviceCategories.map((serviceCategory) => (
                          <CommandItem
                            value={serviceCategory.label}
                            key={serviceCategory.value}
                            onSelect={() => {
                              form.setValue(
                                "serviceCategory",
                                serviceCategory.value
                              );
                            }}
                          >
                            {serviceCategory.label}
                          </CommandItem>
                        ))}
                      </CommandGroup>
                    </CommandList>

Thank you in advance.
I expect to obtain the value for "serviceCategory" based on the selected value from Combobox.

Please use this code in the function:
onSelect={() => {
form.setValue("serviceCategory", serviceCategory.value);
console.log(form.values.serviceCategory); // Add this line
}}
and let me know what you see in you console
